# On click next or previous button request should not go to data base or server in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

When I click on `next page` or `previous page` button to move **crystal report** pages, it goes to database each click.

I saw on once web app first time request goes to server then on click next or previous button this refresh report within mill seconds and it seems this request doesn't hit to data base.

Is it possible to make its cache or like something etc?

Comment: Please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156391/how-to-prevent-crystal-webserver-refetching-data-on-each-page I'm not sure if it's possible what you need...

Comment: First of all thanks for comment. I have already read that post but my question is still that on first request data fetched from database then on pagination it should go back to server shortly I want to ask is there any cache system exists in crystal report.